# Why does linux bash not execute the first command in my pipeline when assigning its output to a variable?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm making a simple script to generate a random word from the file `~/Activities/words` (this is the same as `/usr/share/dict/words`, which my Linux system doesn't have for some reason). I am assigning the output of my pipeline to the variable `$word`. The head command and the - is not highlighted in white as it should be. The script is only running the tail command. I believe it is a Syntax error. How do I fix this?

I've tried putting the pipe in back ticks and `$()`. Both show the same colouring.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

word=$( head -$RANDOM ~/Activities/words | tail -1 ~/Activities/words)
```

- Expected result: A random word each time the script runs
- Actual result: The word is always études (the last word in the words folder, sine only the tail command runs).

Here is a picture of the script as it appears on my computer:

[image]

Comment: You are asking two different questions. William Pursell's answer addresses why your script isn't working which is the real point of your question in spite of the apparent emphasis on syntax highlighting. That is what should be a secondary question. The answer is dependent on what editor you're using and how its syntax highlighting is configured. For me, in `vim`, `head` doesn't get highlighted because it's not listed in `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/sh.vim` (`/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/sh.vim`) which is really odd.

Comment: I have asked a question about this [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20477/1866).

Comment: Also note that your technique won't find words after the 32,767th. The `/usr/share/dict/words` file on my system has 102,255 entries so over two thirds of them would be ignored. See my answer.

Comment: NEVER post images! [mcve]

Comment: @Rob: She posted the code and the image was relevant to the problem.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I would have thought you would know one is not to post images of code, errors or output.

Comment: @Rob: In general, yes, I agree. But in cases like this it's helpful to see what the syntax highlighting looks like so the image is appropriate. Another case would be an image of output such as a hypothetical "why is this sprite exhibiting the glitch shown in this image when I do this code thing (code shown in proper text-mode formatting)?"

Comment: `head` has now been [added](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/10639#issuecomment-1170511655) to Vim's shell highlighting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will output one entry from the word file and store it in the variable:

```
word=$(shuf -n 1 ~/Activities/words)
```

It will search the entire file and won't suffer from the fact that the maximum value of Bash's `$RANDOM` variable is 32767 (using it would ignore any entries after the 32,767th).

Answer (score 3):

The output of `head` is being ignored by `tail`, because you are giving a filename to `tail` as an argument.  Try:

```
word=$( head -$RANDOM ~/Activities/words | tail -1 )
```

But rather than piping head to tail, you could just do:

```
word=$( sed -n -e "$RANDOM{ p; q; }" ~/Activities/words )
```

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Woops!  Thanks.  That's what I get for testing with input generated by `yes | nl `!

Comment: You're welcome. I wonder what happened to the comment.